# ErrorCode: InvalidBlobType when appending to a blob

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to append new lines of json to existing json file in container. Below is my code:

```
import json
import os

from azure.storage.blob import (
    BlockBlobService, AppendBlobService
)
from DBConnection import account_name, container_name, account_key


def getData(self, resp, filename):

        blobService = BlockBlobService(account_name=account_name, account_key=account_key)
        appendblobservice = AppendBlobService(account_name=account_name, account_key=account_key)

        resp = json.dumps(self.resp) #CONVERT FROM DICT TO STR

        filename = self.filename + ".json" #eg: 'ww1_abcded_202002031100.json'

        file_exist = blobService.exists(container_name, filename)

        if file_exist is False:
            print("inside IF")
            blobService.create_blob_from_text(container_name, filename, self.resp)


        else:
            print("Inside else")
            appendblobservice.append_blob_from_text(container_name, filename, self.resp)
            print("2345675t43")
```

I'm getting error at `append_blob_from_text` and producing the following error:

> azure.common.AzureConflictHttpError: The blob type is invalid for this operation. ErrorCode: InvalidBlobType
>   `InvalidBlobType`The blob type is invalid for this operation.

Comment: @GauravMantri I've created a new question. Hopefully you can help! Thanks

Comment: Answered. Why did you delete your previous question?

Comment: I thought it's too silly @GauravMantri

Comment: No question is too silly my friend :).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you're getting this error is because you're calling a method applicable only for `Append Blob` on a `Block Blob`.

Following code of yours creates a Block Blob:

```
blobService.create_blob_from_text(container_name, filename, self.resp)
```

However you're trying to perform an append blob only operation:

```
appendblobservice.append_blob_from_text(container_name, filename, self.resp)
```

Because of this you're getting this error.

Two possible solutions:

1. Create an append blob instead of a block blob if you wish to use append blobs. You can use [`create_blob`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.appendblobservice.appendblobservice?view=azure-python-previous#create-blob-container-name--blob-name--content-settings-none--metadata-none--lease-id-none--if-modified-since-none--if-unmodified-since-none--if-match-none--if-none-match-none--timeout-none-) to create an empty append blob and then append the contents using `append_blob_from_text` method.
2. If you wish to use a block blob, then for appending contents, first you will need to download the blob's contents using [`get_blob_to_text`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.baseblobservice.baseblobservice?view=azure-python-previous#get-blob-to-text-container-name--blob-name--encoding--utf-8---snapshot-none--start-range-none--end-range-none--validate-content-false--progress-callback-none--max-connections-2--lease-id-none--if-modified-since-none--if-unmodified-since-none--if-match-none--if-none-match-none--timeout-none-) method, append the new content and then reupload the blob using [`create_blob_from_text`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.blockblobservice.blockblobservice?view=azure-python-previous#create-blob-from-text-container-name--blob-name--text--encoding--utf-8---content-settings-none--metadata-none--validate-content-false--progress-callback-none--max-connections-2--lease-id-none--if-modified-since-none--if-unmodified-since-none--if-match-none--if-none-match-none--timeout-none-) method.

Comment: I used the first solution and it works out finally! Thank you very much. Just wondering if it is possible to specify the append in a newline rather than `{abc}{def}` to `{abc}\n{def}` from the method itself.